# Moodle upgrade 3.5

Tags: php, mysql, centos7, upgrade, moodle

I am running moodle version 3.4.1 on centos 7 server and I need to upgrade it. From my investigation I understand that running version 3.4.1 cannot be upgraded to the latest version, instead should upgrade to 3.5, correct? (just want to verify this). So my question here is that according to this link: https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Upgrade_overview if you scroll down to "step 3: Replace your moodle code", where can I find the moodle code?

Comment: This is really a question for Moodle support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should upgrade to 3.5 first.
The code for Moodle 3.5 can be found here: https://download.moodle.org/releases/security/